# Client-server user authentication

Tags: ios, security, rest, https, spring-security

**UPDATE:** I failed to mention earlier that we want solution that will be flexible with authenticating users from within our databases or by asking other servers to tell us if the user is authenticated. It is also worth mentioning that these other servers are not under our control so we can't enforce a specific user model.

I had a long and hard read on OAuth and OpenID but they are both not a suitable solution for our situation and will make the process harder to the user. This is something that has been solved a thousand times, yet I cannot find the solution.

What we are looking for is a framework that can be used in a REST services server to authenticate users (no third-party clients involved) with their username and password.
The solution must not pass the username and password except the first time on login and use tokens for further authentication. Even though OAuth does use tokens, it is designed to allow third-party clients access to the service-providers resources. That is not the case here, the services are for our own application only, the only thing needed is user authentication.

**What do you guys think is the most appropriate solution?**

**Configuration:** 
-Spring server that provides RESTful services with our thinking going towards using Spring Security with some user management and token management framework. 
-iOS Device that will be making HTTPS calls to the server.

What we ultimately want is to have the device send a login request and receive a token if the login was successful, later on make requests using that token. Just like Facebook, excluding third-party involvement.

Is there something that is ready to be configured in our server? Or should we consider building our own token management, comparison and generation software?
Is using Spring-Security with an iOS application without involving storing cookies or redirecting to pages possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStack offers as part of it's many projects related to open source cloud... the project Keystone.  Which does this pretty much exactly what you want.

You might want to check it out here:

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still reading through it. Do we have to use OpenStack Identity for our users? or can we use our own username/password comparison process and just use Keystone for token/session management?

Comment: Keystone can tie into ldap or back to PAM atm.  Not much else.  There is some mod work for tying into Active Directory but it's not supported actively by the foundation.